# Django abstract model field name choice

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create an abstract model to implement inheritable functionality to save to a slug field on the save method.

I have something very close, although the only problem is that some models will need a field named "name" and some models will need a field named "title".

Here is what the proxy model looks like:

```
class SaveSlug(models.Model)
    '''
    Save an identifying slug based on the title/name field on save
    '''

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = slug = models.SlugField(db_index=True, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)

        super(SaveSlug, self).save(*args, **kwargs) 

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Everything works fine except that I want to somehow specify in the child models whether to include the "name" field or the "title" field. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good approach would be using a super class for the common fields, and a subclass for name and title.

```
class Slug(models.Model)
    slug = models.SlugField(db_index=True, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class NamedSlug(Slug)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(NamedSlug, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class TitledSlug(Slug)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(TitledSlug, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah that is an improvement. If possible I'd like to get rid of the repeated very similar save method as well.